# Error when attempting to deploy shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am getting an error when trying to deploy a shiny app.

It works fine locally but I get an error when trying to deploy it.

Here is the code

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
rsconnect::deployApp('/Users/tylerreifsteck/Desktop/Marketing ChangeLab/new_app2')
EVILLE<- read_csv("mappingdata.csv")

ui<- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("plot", width = "100%", height = "100%")
)

server<- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      addMarkers(data = EVILLE, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, popup = paste("Company:", dat$`Company Name`, "<br>",
                                                                      "Contact:", dat$`Full Name of Contact`, "<br>",
                                                                      "Phone:", dat$Phone, "<br>",
                                                                    "Address:", dat$address, "<br>",
                                                                    "Business Type:", dat$`Primary NAICS 6 Digit Description`))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The error I receive is :

Error in value[3L] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

I have researched the error but can't find a solution for my problem.

Comment: `dat` object is not defined in your code

Comment: In addition to defining `dat` object, you may need to specify the csv file as `EVILLE<- read_csv("./mappingdata.csv")` when you deploy it on shiny server.

Comment: Whoops on the dat portion. I changed the name of the dataset  as it was a suggestion that came up when searching and forgot to change it in the code. I will try your suggestion @YBS